# Core from exercise 43 of Zed Shaw's Learning Python the hard way doesn't run?

Tags: python, class

He uses this skeleton code to outline the game he wants to create:

```
class Scene(object):

    def enter(self):
        pass


class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        pass

    def play(self):
        pass

class Death(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        pass

class CentralCorridor(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        pass

class LaserWeaponArmory(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        pass

class TheBridge(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        pass

class EscapePod(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        pass


class Map(object):

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        pass

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        pass

    def opening_scene(self):
        pass


a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

He says the uses that last piece of code at the end (last three lines) to run the code and test if it works. When I run it in powershell nothing happens, I know that classes don't run, unless they're called on (which they are in this case right?) So is this supposed to run? Or am I supposed to fill more in? He says:

> In this file you can see that I simply replicated the hierarchy I wanted and then a little bit of code at the end to run it and see if it all works in this basic structure. In the later sections of this exercise you'll fill in the rest of this code and make it work to match the description of the game.

Answer (score 4):

[Pass staments](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) are basically a way to signal to the programmer that the features are not yet implemented, they are essentialy like saying "there will be somehing here". So the program is not supposed to run, it's just a sketch.

Comment: The `pass` statement also allows to have some block without code in it. Check the doc about it (like minimal class or `while True` which wait a InterruptException.

Comment: @Pawelmhm Oh I see, I wondered what that meant but he didn't explicitly say. Thanks for the speedy response.